# CSS list item wrapping to the next line - but only in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

For some bizarre reason, the Home link at the end of this list only wraps around to the next line in IE 9.  Not 8, not 10, not in any other browser.  Any idea how to fix this?! The site is ub-t.com.  Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `#menu-item-36` a `width` of `78px`. Should fit right on. (Happens in Chrome too btw).

It's because there's not enough space for it to fit. Either make the container a bit wider, or give some of them a width to fit them all on

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to fix this. I put [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RG2F6/) together to demonstrate a couple of time-tested solutions, enjoy. If you need more specific help you'll need to post the link to the page or paste in the code.

Here is the fiddle code:
CSS:

```
p {
color: #aaa;
}
div#one {
    width:60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#wrapper, ul#wrapper li {
    /* Setting a common base */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    //margin-right:-4px;
}
#two > div {
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="border:#ccc 1px solid">
 <h3>display: inline-block</h3>

<div id="one">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>Item one
            <div>one</div>
            <div>two</div>
            <div>three</div>
        </div>
        <div>Item two</div>
        <div>Item three</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>This allows us to control when the elements will break to the next line.</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="border:#ccc 1px solid">
    <h3>Float</h3>

    <div id="two">
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;" name="remove this and the border will no longer contain the elements in the div">                 
</div>
</div>
```